# Push Notification Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, google-cloud-platform

I'm a new Windows Phone developer and I'm trying create push notification. I don't understand much about push notification, and have a couple of questions.

1. Push notification windows phone need cloud service,so can I use Google Cloud Service or only use Microsoft Cloud Service.
2. How to register URI from the Microsoft Push Notification Service?

Answer (score 0):

You will have only two options here:
1)MPNS
2)WNS

If you are using WP8 then I will suggest to go with **MPNS** o.w. you can use WNS.

you can use MPNS directly by sending notification URI to server but for WNS you will need to generate secrete key and need to use Azure service.

You can use [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202977(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_RunningtheRawNotificationSample) steps to create server and WP8 App, if you are using MPNS as you are using WP8.

And about GCM you can not use it here.